# Can RC4 ciphers be disabled in Windows Server 2008?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, windows, iis, windows-server

Having some difficulty with disabling RC4 ciphers in Windows Server 2008 SP2. All the guidance I'm seeing for doing this is specific to Windows Server 2008 R2, including the creation of registry keys to modify the ciphers SCHANNEL applications use after installing a patch which enables this functionality (a patch which is only available for R2, not standard: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2868725/microsoft-security-advisory-update-for-disabling-rc4).

Does anyone have any guidance on how to accomplish this? I've seen a lot about the IIS Crypto tool, but I'm wondering if there's any method which does not involve using a third party tool.

Thanks!

Comment: This article might clarify things; https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/245030/how-to-restrict-the-use-of-certain-cryptographic-algorithms-and-protoc